# convert bitset to string?

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this code ?

```
set<string> nk ;
bitset<3> bs1(string("100"));
nk.insert(bs1.to_string());
```

**error:** no matching function for call to `std::bitset<3u>::to_string()'

why?!

**UPDATE :**

Thansk , this works . But why does it work ? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While checking Space_COwbOy's answer, I found [another page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/to_string/) that shows that to_string is a template function (with parameters similar to std::basic_string).  I haven't tried this, so just check it out.

Comment: Yeah, I found that too. I should really read the links I post first :)